# Q: Let |A|=n,|B|=m be finite sets then (Using Inclusion-Exclusion Law)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

due to question above we need to answer
|A∪B|,
|A∩B|

I dont know how solve this question with value of just A and B

this is rules

|A∪B|= |A|+|B - |A∩B|

|A∩B|= |A|+|B| -|A∪B|

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Incomprehensible. What are you asking? You certainly can't find the number of elements of $A\cup B$, nor of $A\cap B$, just from knowing the number of elements of $A$ and of $B$. Simple examples should convince you of this.

Comment: Can you reproduce exactly the whole text of the question here? (And please put the full question in the body of the post, not split between title and body.) Maybe then we can spot the missing information.